# Amcharts funnel chart, how to set fixed height?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have a Funnel chart from https://www.amcharts.com/demos/funnel-chart/?theme=none. It works fine.

I would like to set a fixed height for the segments, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to set fixed height segments directly in the config, but you can fake it using your data by setting fake values for the area/height of the segments but display the real values in a separate property in your `balloonText` and `labelText`, for example:

```
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "title": "Website visits",
    "areaValue": 30, //value used for segment height/area
    "realValue": 300
  }, {
    "title": "Downloads",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 123
  }, // ...
  ],
  // ...
  "valueField": "areaValue", //use the area value for visual purposes
  "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[realValue]]</b>", //reference the actual value through the realValue
  "labelText": "[[title]]: [[realValue]]",
```

Demo below with segments with identical height:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "funnel",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "title": "Website visits",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 300
  }, {
    "title": "Downloads",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 123
  }, {
    "title": "Requested prices",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 98
  }, {
    "title": "Contacted",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 72
  }, {
    "title": "Purchased",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 35
  }, {
    "title": "Asked for support",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 25
  }, {
    "title": "Purchased more",
    "areaValue": 30,
    "realValue": 18
  }],
  "titleField": "title",
  "marginRight": 160,
  "marginLeft": 15,
  "labelPosition": "right",
  "funnelAlpha": 0.9,
  "valueField": "areaValue",
  "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[realValue]]</b>",
  "labelText": "[[title]]: [[realValue]]",
  "startX": 0,
  "neckWidth": "40%",
  "startAlpha": 0,
  "outlineThickness": 1,
  "neckHeight": "30%",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```